# How to make filter and word replacement method for android studio

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

Welcome,. I am making an application to recognize the voice and convert it to text and then compare and correct it, so far everything from converting voice to text and comparing it works perfectly, but there are some words that I want to change or change their wording ... I tried to put it under an if statement As in the place of the code, and it was working well in terms of application, but it affects performance significantly So I was asking if I could make something like a filter so that it contains a large group of words and at the same time maintains a good performance for the application.

An example of what i did :

If(inputText.getText.toString.contains("A Specific Word ")){

String before ;
String after ;

before = inputText.getText.toString;

after = before.replaceAll("A Specific Word", "ASW" );

inputText.setText(after);

}

But this Causes performance problems.

Comment: What do you mean by a performance problem?

Comment: When I put a lot of if statement with the words that I want to replace it takes a long time to processing it

Comment: Are you going to replace all the inputs to "ASW"

Comment: No every single word have its own replacement, keep in mind that These words are limited and specific words from the text, not all words

Comment: For example: if the input text is as follows: "The brown fox jumped over the rock over there and you're on his side." The word I want to change is "you" and replace it with "U" The output becomes: "The brown fox jumped over the rock over there and  U're on his side"

Comment: I think then you have to use those if statements no matter what. But I would recommend you to write a method to pass those inputs and then you will be able to use that method as a single line where you want to execute that code snippet. For an example 
private void replaceText(String input, String contains, String replace){
    input = input.getText.toString();
    contains = "Which words you need to replace";
    replace = "What you have to replace with";

    if(input.contain(contains)){
        input.setText(input.replaceAll(replace));
    }
}

Comment: Please ignore these if I mislead you. This is what would I do if I have to something like that. Please refer to some experts as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simply enhance it by usingthis code:

```
try{
    String sentence = inputText.getText().toString();
    inputText.setText(sentence.replaceall("Hello", "Hi"));    // Replace with Your words
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Couldn't find Hello"); 
}
```

Using try-catch statements it will not check if the word is in there but if it is not there, then also it will continue and will safely pass over the statement.
What is different?
That we are not finding the required word in the sentence which will save time will longer sentences.

Comment: Thank you very much for introducing me to this thing, I will try it. I think this method will work because as you said we are not trying to find the word.

Comment: @Thewiner100Thewiner you said that you will try so did it work? if it didn't i can still help you

Comment: Yes, thanks to your help I was able to complete what I wanted

Comment: I am happy to help:)